# How to get __init__ to return a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here I am trying to return a string but constructor can only return a `None` value. Is there any way around it?

```
class company:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_name = str(input("Enter your first name: "))
        self.last_name = str(input("Enter your last name: "))
        self.fullname = self.first_name + " " +self.last_name
        return self.fullname

class salary:
    pay = int(input("Please enter the pay: "))
    def incre(self):
        self.increment = self.pay + 1000
        return self.increment

class Multiderived(company, salary): # here I am using multiple inheritance
    def output(self):
        company.__init__(self)
        salary.incre(self)
        print ("Your full name is: ", self.fullname)
        print ("Your salary is: ", self.increment)

u = Multiderived()
u.output()
```

In this code I have to use multiple inheritance to access the values of the two super classes, into a single derived class but the constructor of the first super class can't return a string. Is there any way around it.

Comment: `__init__()` can't return a value. You can have a function to return `fullname` like `def get_fullname(self): return self.fullname`.

Comment: *Why* do you want to return a string from `__init__`? Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: What do you expect to happen when `__init__` returns a string? Should `u` contain a `Multiderived` object or a string? What do you expect `u.output` to do if `__init__` were to return a string?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You are breaking python rules by trying to: See documentation of [`object.__init__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__):

> Because [`__new__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) and [`__init__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) work together in constructing objects (`__new__()` to create it, and `__init__()` to customize it), **no non-None value may be returned by `__init__()`**; doing so will cause a `TypeError` to be raised at runtime.

(emphasis **mine**)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are expecting  I am using special method of `__str()__`

```
class Company():
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_name = input("Enter your first name: ")
        self.last_name = input("Enter your last name: ")
        self.fullname = self.first_name + " " +self.last_name
        return self.fullname
class Salary():
    pay = int(input("Please enter the pay: "))
    def incre(self):
        self.increment = self.pay + 1000
        return self.increment
class Multiderived(Company, Salary):
    def __init__(self):
        Company.__init__(self)
        Salary.incre(self)
    def __str__(self):
        return ("Your full name is:"+self.fullname+"\n"+"Your salary is : "+ str(self.increment))
u = Multiderived()
print(u)
```